# Testng related query

Tags: java, testing, maven, testng

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ClassNotFoundException - for testing purposes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12777583/classnotfoundexception-for-testing-purposes)

Is it possible to run a class belonging to some other maven module using a testng present in another module.ie.If a have modules A and B,inside module A i want to use testng.xml to run module 2.Please let me know if its possible.Thanks

I guess its not allowed for testng maybe...

Comment: Yes i tried doing that,But it shows ClassNotFound Exception,i am running through maven so i added the dependency of module 2 in module1's pom.I dont know wat else to do..

Comment: yes maba its the same question.

Comment: Okay i found another way of doing it.I tried to run that testng through java code(not through pom.xml) and it runs perfectly but through eclipse.When i run the same code through commandline it shows the following error.    Cannot instantiate the class module2.I have added to the classpath the folder containing the class module2.

Comment: Welcome on SO. You can edit your original post. Please fill in your updates in your post and not only in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood the essence of your proble,  you should investigate in the direction of maven surefire plugin.
Here is the note about [Unit and Integration Tests With Maven and JUnit Categories](http://johndobie.blogspot.com/2012/04/unit-and-integration-tests-with-maven.html)
From the point of my current project I used following:
[image]

rms-web pom:

```
  <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.11</version>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
                    <artifactId>surefire-junit47</artifactId>
                    <version>2.12</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
                            <configuration>
                <!--<includes>-->
                    <!--<include>**/*.class</include>-->
                <!--</includes>-->
                <excludedGroups>com.exadel.rms.selenium.SeleniumTests</excludedGroups>

            </configuration>

        </plugin>


PassTest.java
package com.exadel.rms.selenium;

import org.junit.Test;

import java.io.IOException;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;

/**
 * Created with IntelliJ IDEA.
 * User: ypolshchykau
 * Date: 8/28/12
 * Time: 8:38 PM
 * To change this template use File | Settings | File Templates.
 */
public class PassTest {


    @Test
    public void pass() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        assertTrue(true);
    }
}


SeleniumTests.java

package com.exadel.rms.selenium;

/**
 * Created with IntelliJ IDEA.
 * User: ypolshchykau
 * Date: 8/27/12
 * Time: 6:49 PM
 * To change this template use File | Settings | File Templates.
 */
public class SeleniumTests {
}


LoginPageTestSuite.java
package com.exadel.rms.selenium;

import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.experimental.categories.Category;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;

import java.io.IOException;

@Category(SeleniumTests.class)
public class LoginPageTestSuite extends BaseSeleniumTest {


    @Test
    public void pressLoginButton() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        doLogout();
        fluentWait(By.cssSelector(propertyKeysLoader("login.loginbutton"))).click();

        Assert.assertTrue(fluentWait(By.cssSelector(propertyKeysLoader("login.validator.invalidautentication"))).getText().trim().equals("Invalid authentication"));
    }
…..........
}
```

After all the described above steps I run console and run following maven command:

```
mvn -Dmaven.buildNumber.docheck=false -Dmaven.buildNumber.doUpdate=false clean test
```

for verifying that all your tagged categories work well.

Hope this somehow helps you.